# SQL Server Finding date in between

Tags: sql-server, date

I have table like below,

In Realtime scenario I have more rows for testing purpose I am attaching only two rows.
[Table]

| Value | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 30-Jun-15 | 30-Jun-16 |
| 20 | 30-Jun-16 | 31-Oct-16 |

If I requested **start date** as ' 31-JUL-2016' and **end date** as '31-AUG-2016',
I need to get only row 2(Second row from table) in above table.

If I requested **start date** as ' 31-AUG-2015' and **end date** as '31-AUG-2016',
I need get all two rows (All row from table) in above table.

How I can achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Please do not [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75285960/2029983) questions. There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75285960/edit) feature you can use.

Comment: Can you clarify your criteria? Are you looking for all records that have a date range that ***overlaps** the requested start-end date range? A standard test for an overlapping date range is `StartDate1 < EndDate2 AND StartDate2 < EndDate1`. You may need to change `<` to `<=` depending on how you need to handle boundary conditions. (It is not uncommon to represent date ranges with an inclusive start-date and an exclusive end-date.

Comment: Start will be exclusive and end will be inclusive

Comment: Yes I am looking for all records that overlaps the requested start and end range. Start will be exclusive and end will be inclusive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
 WHERE '20160731' <= EndDate 
 AND '20160831' >= StartDate;

SELECT * FROM your_table
 WHERE '20150831' <= EndDate
 AND '20160831' >= StartDate;
```